# Items needed to build an automatic watering system

Tags: arduino-uno

I would like to build an automatic watering system. So my research brought me to the following items:

- Breadboard Solderless Prototype PCB Board – ALLDE BB-007 (3pcs) 400 Pin with 4 power Rails and Double Sided Tape
- Capacitive Soil Moisture Sensor (Operating voltage: 3.3 ~ 5.5 VDC, Output voltage: 0 ~ 3.0 VDC, Interface: PH2.54-3P)
- 1 Channel 5V Relay Module (VCC: Connect 5V Positive Pole Power Supply, GND: Connect 5V Negative Pole Power Supply)
- Mini Water Pump (DC Voltage: 3-5 V)
- Arduino UNO REV3 [A000066]

I am beginner in electronics so I have some very basic questions. Given the above specifications, and assuming I would like to power this system with battery and not to a power outlet, what battery do I need to power up the Arduino? I would like to have this system running for at most 30 days. The system will be running constantly until the moisture sensor indicates that watering is needed, in which case will run the mini water pump for some time (I don't know how long this will be running).

Could a battery power up this system? I am not sure if I can link products, but this system is based on [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TLRYGT1) system if I forgot to include some critical information about the system.

So to summarize, is is possible to power up this system with a battery pack, if so which battery should I use?

Comment: Depending on the actual power needs (mainly of the pump motor), you might get away with a simple USB power bank with enough capacity. Though some power banks cut the power completely, if you don't draw a minimal current from them.

Comment: what is your water source and how big a garden bed or pot are you watering? If you are connecting to a tap, why use a pump? If you are not, can you design it to gravity feed the water?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest feeding the system with a 12V lead-acid battery and a buck DC/DC converter with 5V output. (Those are more efficient than the regulators in Arduinos.) You could feed the regulated 5V directly into the USB port on your Arduino. You'll probably need a filtering capacitor on the Arduino 5V input to reduce fluctuations in power as the pump turns on and off however.

You'll need to do some back-of-the-envelope calculations on the power consumption of the Arduino, the on current of the water pump, the expected max duty cycle of the pump, and the efficiency of the DC/DC converter. That will let you estimate the power consumption of the whole system in mW/hr. You can then get a battery big enough to power it for your desired run-time. If you add a solar powered charging system you could increase your run-time or even make it run purely on solar power (with a big enough panel and enough bright sunshine.)

Answer (score 0):

For start, I would be seriously supprised if 5 volt pump does much good and vould start from 12VDC (car or campa-van stuff...) I would be supprised if you do not have 12DC supply around (from old router, chinese gimic sliming devices, christmas light box, cable setup-box...)
Don't panic, You may be able to get relay capable of switching higher Voltages.

Second: Newer connect anything that has solenoid directly to arduino. (not even relay). Most IC's or MCU's are only able to handle opening mosfet or a transistor, only some can handle one LED. Although in the moment relay switches off, it (its induced current) will take Arduino with it. if instead you use some common cheap NPN transistor and a diode across(in opposite direction).
I recommend soldering. relays and the things you power from them.
last get an IP55 box from nearest electric shop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsxitx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And lastly I would have replaced UNO for NANO here. Its much more compacr and fits easily into IP55 box
 For battery you van use car battery...
I Find since Yuasa started destroying (buying ) competition, the lead-acids lifespan gone far down (on alarms often insufficient in a year)